# PHP mail() function not working properly

Tags: php, email

I use PHP mail() function to send emails from my website. No problems with addresses, headers etc...
The function actually sends emails, but it seems that they can't reach some specific addresses.

Examples:

1. mail from x@domain1.com to x@domain1.com,y@domain2.com - received on
   x, not received on y
2. mail from x@domain1.com to y@domain2.com,x@domain1.com - received on
   x, not received on y
3. mail from y@domain2.com to x@domain1.com,y@domain2.com - received on
   x, not received on y
4. mail from y@domain2.com to y@domain2.com,x@domain1.com - received on
   x, not received on y

why is this happening?

Comment: Are you mailing both recipients with one `mail()` call or two? Does either domain1.com or domain2.com exist on the same server or hosting environment at your PHP script?

Comment: I use only one 'mail()' call and neither domain1.com nor domain2.com are on the same server of my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending mail, and it's being received by one person but not another, the problem is almost always due to an issue at the receiver's end.

I'd say that your email is most likely getting stuck in a spam filter somewhere. An email sent through PHP tends to look very like email that's been sent by a spammer - you've got a `From:` header that doesn't match the server that sent it, and it's been sent to multiple people. Do you also have a `Reply-to:` header set, too?

If you use your code to send as basic an email as you can, see if that gets through to y; then you can start adding in the extra headers until you get to the point that it stops working again....

Comment: I think you're right, problems are on receiver's end. I've setted both 'From:' and 'Reply-to:' as sender's address, just like 'Return-Path:'.

Comment: I've contacted domain2.com owners to ask about this problem

Comment: Do you need the Reply-to in there, if you're already using their email address as From? That might be enough to sort it, all by itself....